# Proving a Legendre function using generating function: $\int_{-1}^1 (1-2xt+t^2)^{-1/2}P_n(x)dx=\frac{2t^n}{2n+1}$

Tags: special-functions

I must prove that $\int_{-1}^1 (1-2xt+t^2)^{-1/2}P_n(x)dx=\frac{2t^n}{2n+1}$.

I know that the generating function is $(1-2xt+t^2)^{-1/2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty P_n(x)t^n$. I also know that the orthogonality property when l=m gives   $\frac{2}{2n+1}$.

I get to where I have $\sum_{n=0}^\infty t^n(\frac{2}{2n+1})$.

Any ideas on how to get the correct answer or where I may be going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> You are calculating for 'a given' $\ds{\,\mathrm{P}_{n}\pars{x}}$
>   $\ds{~\pars{\mbox{namely, for 'a given'}\ n}~}$. You must use another index for the generating function $\ds{~\pars{n\ \mbox{is a constant}}~}$ such as $\ds{m}$ which I'll use below !!!.

\begin{align}
&\color{#f00}{%
\int_{-1}^{1}\pars{1 - 2xt + t^{2}}^{-1/2}\,\,\,\mathrm{P}_{n}\pars{x}\,\dd x}
=
\int_{-1}^{1}\overbrace{%
\bracks{\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}t^{m}\,\mathrm{P}_{m}\pars{x}}}
^{\ds{\pars{1 - 2xt + t^{2}}^{-1/2}}}
\,\mathrm{P}_{n}\pars{x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}t^{m}\ \underbrace{%
\int_{-1}^{1}\,\mathrm{P}_{m}\pars{x}\,\mathrm{P}_{n}\pars{x}\,\dd x}
_{\ds{2\,\delta_{mn} \over 2n + 1}}\ =\
\color{#f00}{{2\,t^{n} \over 2n + 1}}
\end{align}

Comment: All too easy.  +1